# Geometric explanation of the formula for double cross product

Tags: geometry, vectors, cross-product

Let $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{c}$ be vectors in the space $\mathbb{E}^3$. Then it’s easy to check by calculation that the following equation holds:
$$\mathbf{a}\times (\mathbf{b}\times \mathbf{c})=(\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{c}) \mathbf{b}-(\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b}) \mathbf{c}.$$

However, the textbook says the equation can be explained geometrically, and I wonder how. All that has come to me so far is that the vector $\mathbf{a}\times (\mathbf{b}\times \mathbf{c})$ lies on the plane spanned by $\mathbf{b},\mathbf{c}$ (given that they are not parallel), but what exactly can represent the **double cross product** geometrically? Please help.

Comment: Have a look at the illustration on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Properties that compares $a\times(b\times c)$ to $(a\times b)\times c$, which decomposes the product into projections onto a certain plane.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400641/do-the-bac-cab-identity-for-triple-vector-product-have-some-intepretation/400732#400732) will help.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute value of the product may be written as $|a×(b×c)|=|a||b×c|\sin\phi,$ where $\phi$ is the deviation between $a$ and $b×c.$

Since the segment with length $|a|\sin\phi$ is orthogonal to the one with length $|b×c|,$ you may interpret the product as describing a rectangle with sides $a\sin\phi,\,b×c,$ and the absolute value of the product gives its area.

Comment: No, this is wrong. You get the volume by taking $|a\cdot (b\times c)|$.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin, again, you're right. And, thank you. See edit however.

Comment: How does this begin to explain the formula the OP gave — the classic formula?

Comment: Sorry, I fail to see how this relates to the equation, could you please explain it in more detail?