# Proof of equation relating to vector triple product and BAC-CAB rule

Tags: cross-product

I am currently studying *Introduction to Electrodynamics*, fourth edition, by David J. Griffiths. Chapter **1.1.3 Triple Products** introduces the **vector triple product** as follows:

> **(ii) Vector triple product:** $\mathbf{A} \times (\mathbf{B} \times \mathbf{C})$. The vector triple product can be simplified by the so-called **BAC-CAB** rule:
>
> $$\mathbf{A} \times (\mathbf{B} \times \mathbf{C}) = \mathbf{B}(\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{C}) - \mathbf{C}(\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B}). \tag{1.17}$$
>
> Notice that
>
> $$(\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B}) \times \mathbf{C} = - \mathbf{C} \times (\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B}) = - \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{C}) + \mathbf{B}(\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{C})$$
>
> is an entirely different vector (cross-products are not associative). All *higher* vector products can be similarly reduced, often by repeated application of Eq. 1.17, so it is never necessary for an expression to contain more than one cross product in any term. For instance,
>
> $$(\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B}) \cdot (\mathbf{C} \times \mathbf{D}) = (\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{C})(\mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{D}) - (\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{D})(\mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{C});$$
>
> $$\mathbf{A} \times [ \mathbf{B} \times (\mathbf{C} \times \mathbf{D})] = \mathbf{B}[\mathbf{A} \cdot (\mathbf{C} \times \mathbf{D})] - (\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B})(\mathbf{C} \times \mathbf{D}). \tag{1.18}$$

I am trying to prove that

$$(\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B}) \cdot (\mathbf{C} \times \mathbf{D}) = (\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{C})(\mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{D}) - (\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{D})(\mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{C})$$

I attempted to prove this in the comments to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3692168/356308) answer of a related question that I had asked. However, as you can see, it is still not clear to me how this is done.

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify how this is done.

Answer (score 1):

$(A\times B)\cdot(C\times D)=(A\times B)\cdot E=A\cdot(B\times E)$
where  $E=C\times D$, and by the scalar triple product identity.
Then $B\times E=B\times(C\times D)=(B\cdot D)C-(B\cdot C)D$ by
the vector triple product identity. Now dot this with $A$.

Comment: I don't understand how $(A\times B)\cdot E=A\cdot(B\times E)$. Can you please clarify this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Properties @ThePointer