# Triple product proof

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, cross-product

I am trying to prove the identity $a\times(b\times c)=\langle a,c\rangle b-\langle a,b\rangle c$

Like other proofs (such as this [one](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-prove-that-A-X-B-X-C-B-A-C-C-A-B)) , I have managed to find that $a\times(b\times c)=\lambda\langle a,c\rangle\cdot b-\lambda\langle a,b\rangle\cdot c$

That is true for some $\lambda \in \mathbb R$, in the proof that I mentioned above, they state that this constant $\lambda$ is the same for all three vectors $a,b,c\in\mathbb R^3$.

I just cant understand why this constant is the same for every trio, I would appreciate any explanation, Thanks.

Comment: The easiest is to use the identity $(a \times b)^i = \epsilon^{ijk} a^j b^k$ where $\epsilon^{ijk}$ is the Levi-Civita symbol.

Comment: Quora is not the place where I would search for answers for technical questions. The most straightforward way to prove the identity is to just represent all vectors in the standard Euclidean basis.

Comment: In particular, @Mathphysmeister's approach uses $\epsilon^{ijk}\epsilon_{ilm}=\delta^j_l\delta^k_m-\delta^k_l\delta^j_m$. This has a proof in terms of antisymmetries using logic similar to one part of my answer.

Comment: @J.G. this is indeed right. Thanks for elaborating on my comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do the BAC-CAB identity for triple vector product have some intepretation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400641/do-the-bac-cab-identity-for-triple-vector-product-have-some-intepretation)

Comment: I would love to help but I don't understand what you mean by "this constant  is the same for all three vectors ,,∈$ℝ^3$"?